# Excel add-on instances

Tags: excel, excel-addins, exceljs

Is it possible to make the excel add-on in sync in two workbooks.

Following is the use case:

a. Our add-on required login, after login user can use the application.

b. When user open's add-on in other workbook, the add-on is starting from beginning. It means user has to login again. The expected is, add-on need to use the session opened in the first workbook.

Does it supported? Any configuration changes?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain the user session in registry as per user. For example if you are using OAuth then you can maintain the token in the registry. When you try to open the second workbook then you can check if you have an existing token(a valid one).

Comment: Can you please share an example or reference document/s.